# Ввод даты в языке Си

Tags: c

Нужно пару раз ввести дату для разных событий и дабы не писать нечто страшное для события 1

```
    printf("Введите год заказа %d-го покупателя: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &reader[i].z_year);

    printf("Введите месяц заказа %d-го покупателя: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &reader[i].z_month);

    printf("Введите день заказа %d-го покупателя: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &reader[i].z_day);
```

И подобное для других событий, можно ли как-то ввод сделать а-ля введите дату заказа
пользователь вводит дату в формате 29.11.2018, а мы получаем в переменную год 2018, месяц 11 ну и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно. Форматированный ввод предоставляет такую возможность.

```
scanf("%d.%d.%d", &reader[i].z_day, &reader[i].z_month, &reader[i].z_year);
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, `1..1.....1111` тоже прочитается?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет https://ideone.com/4XEq8M

Comment: Да, [точно](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/): _"Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread."_

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/D082Rz

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  int d, m, y;

  printf("Вводите даты заказов в формате dd.MM.yyyy\n");

  while (scanf("%d%*1[.]%d%*1[.]%d", &d, &m, &y) == 3)
    printf("Принято: %02d.%02d.%04d\n", d, m, y);

  return 0;
}
```